# Changing menu styles using jQuery and master pages in ASP .NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, master-pages

I have created a vertical menu on a ASP.NET master page using jQuery. Here are some items to consider:

- The menu structure is based on ordered lists . List items have nested items (UL) containing sub-menu options.
- All sub-menus must appear collapsed when the page is loaded. This is easily done by having display: none for the sub-menu style rule. However, this web site is supposed to run even when Java Script is disabled. So I thought I would se the sub-menu rule style to display: block and change the display back to 'none' during $(document).ready(function ()). So if JavaScript is disabled the menu will appear with all sub-menu items already expanded.

The problem:
Currently when JavaScript is enabled, the page is loaded with all sub-menu options expanded and then after jQuery ready method is run the sub-menu are collapsed using:

```
$('.menu li > .sub-menu').hide();
```

I would like to show the page with all sub-menu items already collapsed and avoid the collapsing of sub-menu items after the page is loaded. How can I achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: I think `.hide()` defaults to animating the objects till they're hidden - think it is half a second or something. This could be what you're seeing. Try using `.hide(0)` instead.

Comment: Just looked up the .hide function - it appears it has changed in recent versions and now defaults to hiding immediately.. I swear it used to animate by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer, I think. What you want is to set the CSS for those sub menus to `display: none;` and then create a duplicate sub menu in a noscript tag. If JS is enabled, the noscript version is not displayed, nor is the other due to the CSS. If JS is disabled, the CSS acts on the JS version but the noscript tag kicks in.

Comment: Thanks ClarkeyBoy - I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have 2 versions of your menu, possibly you could use the **noscript** tag and put your non-javascript menu version in there

Or another option is maybe you could add a **script** tag right after the menu with

```
$('.menu li > .sub-menu').hide();
```

without the $(document).ready

Comment: Thank yoou for your reply. Unfortunately adding the script tag after the menu didn't work.